# How to find the min of the previous n values for every element of a vector?

Tags: r, loops, min

So far I use loops within a function like this:

```
# x is a vector of numbers
# [1] 0 1 -1 -5 100 20 15

function(x,n){

  results <- numeric(length(x)-n+1)

  for(i in 1:(length(x)+1-n)){
    results[i] <- min(x[i:(i+n-1)])
  }

  return(results)
}

## outputs this for x and n = 3
# [1] -1 -5 -5 -5 15
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient solution that potentially does not require looping.

EDIT::

I ran two of the solutions with microbenchmark on a vector with 6019 observations. When I get the time (/figure out how), I can try each solution with various observation sizes to see the effectiveness of each solution. But for now:

Rcpp Solution:

```
> microbenchmark(nmin(x,3))
Unit: microseconds
       expr    min     lq     mean  median     uq    max neval
 nmin(x, 3) 53.885 54.313 57.01953 54.7405 56.023 93.656   100
```

caTools solution:

```
microbenchmark(runmin(x[[1]],3,endrule='trim'))
Unit: microseconds
                                expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq     max neval
 runmin(x[[1]], 3, endrule = "trim") 231.788 241.8385 262.6348 249.964 262.5795 833.923   100
```

zoo Solution:

```
> microbenchmark(rollapply(x[[1]],3,min))
Unit: milliseconds
                      expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 rollapply(x[[1]], 3, min) 42.2123 47.2926 50.40772 50.33941 52.50033 98.46828   100
```

my Solution:

```
  > microbenchmark(nDayLow(x[[1]],3))
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 nDayLow(x[[1]], 3) 13.64597 14.51581 15.67343 15.33006 15.71324 63.68687   100
```

Comment: runmin seems to give the fastest result so far

Comment: @road_to_quantdom You didn't test the `Rcpp` solution?

Comment: sorry for the delay, I just ran the solution now. Yours does seem to be the most efficient!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a good use-case for *Rcpp*. Copy-paste this and use it like any other function. I am sure there are many ways to make this even more efficient (what I mean to say is that I am not particularly good at c++ and I'm pretty sure you can make use of some nice STLs here):

```
require(Rcpp)
Rcpp::cppFunction( 'IntegerVector nmin( NumericVector x , int n ){
  int N = x.size();
  IntegerVector out(N-n+1);
    for( int i = 0; i < out.size(); ++i){
        int nmin=x[i];
        for( int j = 0; j < n; ++j){
          int tmp=x[j+i];
          if( tmp < nmin ){
            nmin=tmp;
          }
        }
        out[i]=nmin;
    }
  return out;
}')

nmin(x,3)
#[1] -1 -5 -5 -5 15
nmin(x,7)
#[1] -5
```

It's about 30-fold quicker than `runmin`:

```
print( microbenchmark(runmin(x,3,endrule='trim'),nmin(x,3),unit="relative") , digits = 1 )
#Unit: relative
#                           expr min lq median uq max neval
# runmin(x, 3, endrule = "trim")  55 41     36 34  19   100
#                     nmin(x, 3)   1  1      1  1   1   100
```

Comment: how would you do this if the vectors were type "double"

Answer (score 4):

Use `rollapply` from **zoo**:

```
library("zoo")
rollapply(x, 3, min)
# [1] -1 -5 -5 -5 15
```

Comment: thanks. I just ran two microbenchmarks to see performance difference. It seems that the for-loop method might actually be faster. I am shocked, but could that be possible?

Comment: @road_to_quantdom In almost all cases, `*apply` functions are just syntactic sugar around a for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `runmin` from `caTools`

```
library(caTools)
runmin(x,3,endrule='trim')
#[1] -1 -5 -5 -5 15
```